# Stop windows service when i need admin privileges

Tags: java, exception, command-line, process, windows-services

Here i have String to save command for start command line as administrator and stop windows service. It says in console: Enter the password for Administrator:

```
String administratorCommandLine = "runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c sc stop AcPrfMgrSvc\"";
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(administratorCommandLine);
runtimeProcess.waitFor();

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (runtimeProcess.getInputStream());

BufferedWriter stdOutput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
runtimeProcess.getOutputStream()));
```

When i want to add password to commandline as required that tells exception: 
Exception : java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed

```
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
if(s.startsWith("Enter the password for Administrator:") || s.startsWith("Zadejte heslo pro administrator:")) { 
stdOutput.append("password123").flush(); 
} 
}
```

Is there any possible way how to put password into that stream?

Comment: I think, providing password from OutputStream like this may not work. Try prompting for the password before launching the process and then launch the process with PsExec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) with the username and password supplied.

Comment: could u post there the code which i have to used exactly?, but thanks its a good idea

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    String loggedInUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String pass="";

    String psexec = "C:\\Utils\\psexec.exe"; //location of psexec
    //Build the command line
    List<String> command = new LinkedList<String>();
    command.add(psexec);
    command.add("-u");
    command.add("Administrator");

    //request password if the user is not Administrator
    if(! loggedInUser.equalsIgnoreCase("Administrator")) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        pass = s.nextLine();
        if(! pass.trim().isEmpty()) {
            command.add("-p");
            command.add(pass);
        }
    }       

    command.add("cmd.exe");
    String[] cmdArgs = {"/c", "sc", "stop", "AcPrfMgrSvc"};
    command.addAll(Arrays.asList(cmdArgs));

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = builder.start();

    int returnCode;

    try {
        returnCode = process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        returnCode = 1;
    }
```

PS: I know reading password as String using Scanner is insecure and not a good idea. My code above is primarily written to demonstrate the use of PsExec for stopping a Windows service as Administrator. You should probably replace the password reading code with a better version as explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: hm.. this code makes error: Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: at which line of code? btw, you HAVE to enter a password when prompted. As I said, the code is for showing how to use PsExec and not for inputting the password.